# File transfer on hamachi without ftp server: is this possible?

Tags: ssh, vpn, ftp, sftp, hamachi

Is it possible to transfer files with protocols like ftp on a hamachi network without any permition or requirement to a ftp server?

Thank you.

Comment: If the two are on the same Hamachi LAN you could use file sharing, http server, ftp, almost any local file sharing protocol

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, not using FTP.

## FTP

So far as I know, Hamachi is a VPN. It simply makes two computers appear to be on the same LAN. It doesn't provide any other special application-level services.

Any normal use of FTP requires one computer to act as an FTP client (e.g. by running the `ftp` command) and the other computer to act as an FTP server (e.g. by running an `ftpd` daemon or equivalent service).

With or without a VPN you may be able to use a public FTP service as an intermediary - first `FTP PUT` from PC1 to a public FTP server, then on PC2 use  `FTP GET` to retrieve the file from that public FTP server and finally use `FTP DELE` to delete the file from the public service. Both PCs act as FTP clients, neither act as an FTP server.

The public FTP server could be anything for which you have valid credentials - it could be a cheap website hosting service you already pay for (assuming upload limits, storage limits etc are not exceeded).

## Other

FTP is not the only file transfer protocol, the ones I can think of all follow the client-server model.